# Text Input in HTML Form won't show up

Tags: php, html, css, forms, input

I am working on a text-based online game (that is horribly incomplete), and I'm using PHP mainly. In my HTML I have a form (text input) for commands for my game, but it just won't show up. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
    <?php
        include_once 'game.php';
    ?>
    </div>
    <FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="">
        <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" name="input"
            style="width: 600; position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 2;">
        </INPUT>
    </FORM>
    <?php
        $input = $_POST["input"];
    ?>
</div>
```

So it's really the FORM and the INPUT that screws me over since it doesn't show up. I also have this as my CSS, if it helps:

```
.main {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container {
    width: 602px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And of course I have my `game.php` but I don't feel like that's the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Based on people's answers, it's probably the PHP. Here's the entire code for the game.php file, I have no idea what's wrong.

```
<?php
include_once 'index.php';
$World = simplexml_load_file("gameworld.xml");
$CurrentPos = 0;
$Done = 0;
print "<br>";
printplace();
function printplace() {
    GLOBAL $World, $CurrentPos;
    $Room = $World->ROOM[$CurrentPos];
    $Name = $Room->NAME;
    $Desc = wordwrap((string)$Room->DESC);
    print "$Name<br>";
    print str_repeat('-', strlen($Name));
    print "<br>$Desc<br>";
    if ((string)$Room->NORTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->NORTH;
        print "North: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$Room->SOUTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->SOUTH;
        print "South: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->WEST;
        print "West: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->EAST;
        print "East: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    print "<br>";
}

while (!$Done) {
    print "<br>"; // add another line break after the user input

    $input = split(' ', $input);

    switch(trim($input[0])) {
        case 'north':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go north!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'south':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go south!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'west':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go west!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'east':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go east!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'look':
            printplace() ;
            break;
        case 'quit':
            $Done = 1;
            break;
    }
}

print "<br>Thanks for playing!<br>";
?>
```

Really, it's just a branch off of http://www.hackingwithphp.com/21/4/2/text-game-v1
that I tried to port to browsers but it failed horribly...

Comment: If you remove `include('game.php')` does the problem go away?

Comment: When I load your web page, it pegs my CPU.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too. I'm not sure though. When I tried it last time, it yielded no results.

Comment: Huh. I wonder. Somethings wrong then... Well, I mean, no duh but let me check.

Comment: Yeah. I commented out include('game.php'); and everything works fine. I updated the website without the game.php.

Comment: I also was unable to download the page with `curl` before you removed `game.php`, I got an empty response. Now I can get it. So I suspect `game.php` may have been looking for something that a browser sends but `curl` doesn't.

Comment: FYI, the `<input>` tag does not have a matching closing tag (there is no such thing as `</input>`). http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: @Dan Lowe alright, noted. Thanks.

Comment: Your PHP just goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

It shows up fine in Chrome and in Firefox. See below.

```css
.main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container {
  width: 602px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
  </div>
  <FORM NAME="form1" METHOD="POST" ACTION="">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" name="input" style="width: 600; position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 2;">
    </INPUT>
  </FORM>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. It might be the php then? Look at urbanadventure.dumpong.tk. That's the actual site of the game... It doesn't work on there.

Comment: That page doesn't finish loading and just completely crashed my browser. Twice.

Comment: It works, but only after I commented out include('game.php');. So it's probably the PHP's problem...